# How can I show a dynamic welcome message using Amazon lex bot?

Tags: chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot, amazon-lex

I am developing a chatbot using Amazon lex. It is going to be integrated with facebook messenger in a facebook page. When a user opens the bot for the first time, it says nothing. It listens to user intents. I would like the bot to initiate a conversation and provide the user with a few options(configured in a mysql database in the backend). What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

**There is a `get_started` event which you can subscribe to with FB Messenger**

See the [Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/get-started-button)

When triggered, hit your db to get whatever response is appropriate based on the context you have from the event, and anything in your DB.